# Can't run Android Studio's Emulator

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I guess it was because after run instrumented test file so become can't open Android Studio's emulator?
But I am not sure.

Error message:
Launching 'app' on No Devices.
Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD Pixel_4_XL_API_30 was killed.

[image]

Comment: Can you launch the emulator manually from AVD Manager?

Comment: @Martheen I can't launch the emulator manually from AVD Manager,too.

Comment: Edit your question with the error message on launching the emulator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used follow solution solved this problem.↓

```
Tools -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools (tab) -> Deselect 'Android Emulator' -> OK

Now, when you try to run your app, or launch device from AVD Manager, it will give the 'Install Emulator' error -> Click Ok. This will automatically download the correct version.
```

Comment: Unfortunately, This solution did not help me. API 30 and 31 have issues with the emulator. Especially in Arctic Fox, it doesn't even start. https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2021/04/android-studio-arctic-fox-canary-15.html

Comment: Still failed on
Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8193401, built on February 17, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 10.15.7

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem with emulator version 30.6.4 and Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Canary 15. I tried switching from Intel HAXM to Windows Hyper-V and re-installed all android build tool and emulator packages. Afterwards it worked for a day.

The second thing I tried is manually installing an older version (30.5.5) of the emulator which you can get from [here](https://androidsdkoffline.blogspot.com/p/android-sdk-emulators-download.html). Now Android Studio does not recognize my manual installation of the emulator and I can not start the AVD from the UI. However I can start it via cmd and install apps from within android studio without crashes (at least for the moment).

Start your AVD with the following command (android/sdk/emulator):

```
emulator -avd <name-with-_-instead-of-spaces>
```